# Spacy import errors out Undefined Symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, spacy

I've already asked to the developers on their GitHub issues page, but nothing is helping so far
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/855

Created a new env with conda

`conda create -n spacy python=3.5 ipython`

and then install spacy (1.6.0) with pip (conda still has version 0.101.0)

`pip install spacy`

But I still get this error.

```
In [1]: import spacy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c080f6458562> in <module>()
 ----> 1 import spacy

 /home/alexis/anaconda3/envs/spacy/lib/python3.5/site- packages/spacy/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 from .about import __version__
      5
----> 6 from . import en
      7 from . import de
      8 from . import zh

/home/alexis/anaconda3/envs/spacy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/en/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from ..util import match_best_version
      7 from ..util import get_data_path
----> 8 from ..language import Language
      9 from ..lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
     10 from ..vocab import Vocab

/home/alexis/anaconda3/envs/spacy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/language.py in <module>()
     15
     16
---> 17 from .tokenizer import Tokenizer
     18 from .vocab import Vocab
     19 from .tagger import Tagger

ImportError: /home/alexis/anaconda3/envs/spacy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/tokenizer.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E
```

I did source the new conda environment and pip is the one from that new env. I'm running out of options here.

There is a similar issue here explosion/sense2vec#19 but that solution did not help.

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Note, I don't have that problem on MacOS Sierra.

---

Update

I've exported my conda environment from MacOS (where it's working) and created a new one on the machine where it doesn't work. Same stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

I saw on a sense2vec issues page https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec/issues/19 to do `conda install libgcc` and it worked for me.